# How do I use python packages I've already installed in other IDEs

Tags: python, import, pip, path, ide

I started learning python using Jupyter and have used it since to install packages and import them. However recently I installed PyCharm and am not able to import any of the installed packages.

Within Jupyter no matter how much I try the version of python does not update beyond 3.8. With respect to Path variables I've added python 3.9 into the path variable.

How do I use the previously installed libraries with other IDEs such as PyCharm and SublimeText?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-install it in this new ide.

Each ide is a virtual environment, so installing a module in that ide only installs it for that ide.
That is the main point of environments, you can install the same packages but different versions in each environment.
However one downfall is you need to install the package several times.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

in pycharm after you install module by using pip.You should install the module from library of pycharm also because sometimes pycharm doesn't add that module to project file so you should follow: 
on the left top of screen in pycharm File>>Settings>>Project:FİLENAME>>Python interpreter >>
 '+' button on the left bottom corner >>  search the module you want >> install it >> then ready to go